# Where does Augustine say that the rapture of the saved soul will "flow over" into the glorified body?

Tags: heaven, cs-lewis, augustine, resurrection-body

In [*The Weight of Glory*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WNTT_8NW_qwC&pg=PA44), C. S. Lewis writes:

> What would it be to taste at the fountainhead that stream of which even these lower reaches prove so intoxicating?  Yet that, I believe, is what lies before us.  The whole man is to drink joy from the fountain of joy.  **As St. Augustine said, the rapture of the saved soul will "flow over" into the glorified body.**  In light of our present specialised and depraved appetites, we cannot imagine this *torrens voluptatis*, and I warn everyone most seriously not to try.

I haven't been able to find where Augustine actually said this.  Where in Augustine's writings is the original quote and its context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arend Smilde](http://lewisiana.nl/essayquotes/#weight) finds the answer to this question in [Augustine's letter to Dioscorus (CXVIII)](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf101.vii.1.CXVIII.html), 3.14:

> Now, perfect health of body shall be the consummation of the immortality of the whole man. For God has endowed the soul with a nature so powerful, that **from that consummate fulness of joy which is promised to the saints in the end of time, some portion overflows also upon the lower part of our nature, the body**,—not the blessedness which is proper to the part which enjoys and understands, but the plenitude of health, that is, the vigour of incorruption.

The reference to *torrens voluptatis* is apparently distinct, using phrasing from the Vulgate and Augustine's [exposition of Psalm 35:9](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf108.ii.XXXVI.html) (or, [36:8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm+36%3A8&version=ESV)):

> “And of the torrent of Thy Pleasure shalt Thou give them to drink.” [et torrente voluptatis tuae potabis eos] A torrent we call water coming with a flood. There will be a flood of God’s Mercy to overflow and inebriate those who now put their trust under the shadow of His wings. What is that Pleasure? As it were a torrent inebriating the thirsty. Let him then who thirsts now, lay up hope: whoso thirsts now, let him have hope; when inebriated, he shall have possession: before he have possession, let him thirst in hope. “Blessed are they which do hunger and thirst after righteousness, for they shall be filled.”